# Calling a function from a different module to set an argument ELM

Tags: elm

So I have been trying to learn ELM recently and I love it but I get stuck quite often. What I did in the code below is created a module and called it "Operation" then imported another module with a function I wanted to use. This is the task I was given by colleague as practice: "Create an Elm module called Operation. Import module StatusCalc and expose everything from it. Inside it create function “work” which receives an Int (called “exec”) as an argument, and returns Status. Its task is to call the function “checker” from module StatusCalc by giving it “exec” as an argument. I did the majority of it but the last part "Its task is to call the function “checker” from module StatusCalc by giving it “exec” as an argument".

Module: StatusCalc code:

```
 module StatusCalc exposing (..)

type Status
 = Started
 | PartiallyDone
 | Done

checker: Int -> Status
checker nameless =
  if nameless <= 0 then Started
  else if nameless < 10 then PartiallyDone
  else Done
```

Module: Operation

```
module Operation exposing (..)

import StatusCalc exposing (..)

work: Int -> Status
```

Comment: What's the problem preventing you from just doing that?

Comment: I do not understand how to do that part ""Its task is to call the function “checker” from module StatusCalc by giving it “exec” as an argument"

Comment: I don't understand how to call the function "checker" and give it the exec argument.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: The above code is all my typing, there was a lot more steps prior to that. I just got stuck on that part.

Comment: Then I suggest you try something to solve the last part too, and if even the most obvious thing you try doesn't work, report back here with the code you tried and the problem with it.

Comment: Read the docs about [modules](https://guide.elm-lang.org/webapps/modules.html). Don't concentrate on the JSON stuff in the example, it's unnecessary details at this point. Also "functions" section in core [language docs](https://guide.elm-lang.org/core_language.html) are useful. And don't give up, you're very close to finding the solution :)

Comment: Managed to do it after reading more into the Modules link you sent. Thank you.